# How do I debug exceptions in unknown code?

Tags: c++, debugging, exception, assembly

I have a program that uses external libraries. One of the libraries (responsible for a camera hardware) starts a thread and crashes unpredictably. Sometimes every 2 minutes, sometimes not for an hour. There's no obvious trigger. The exception is not caught be the thread, which leads to a termination of the application. :(

Luckily I can stop the application in the moment the exception is raised by the `RaiseException()` function from the `kernel32.dll`. There are no other functions on the call stack of which I know what they are for.

The debugger told me, that it's a std::bad_alloc exception. How does the debugger know that? Can I get more information about the exception somehow? If necessary, I would look into the Disassembly, but I don't know where to look to get the information.

I'm using Visual Studio C++ 2010, am well acquainted with assembler and have some understanding of the WINAPI. We want to release this software soon and this bug MUST dissappear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use Windbg instead, that is a  hard-core debugger that hides nothing and exposes things 'as they are'. Using `sxe` syntax enable the desired exception (Windgb will enable to break at any SEH type, not only C++). Windbg also has a clear distinction between first chance exception and second chance exception. You should figure out then whether this is a C++ exception being raise or a more fundamental SEH type like perhaps an AV.

Comment: It's a C++ exception, since it's std::bad_alloc, therefore it's no SEH exception. The exception is first chance. Are there any exception parameters or something like that, which I can read out? If so, how?

Comment: Note that all C++ exceptions are SEH exceptions (code e06d7363). See http://www.drdobbs.com/visual-c-exception-handling-instrumentat/184416600 or  http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2126/How-a-C-compiler-implements-exception-handling for a discussion of how to get the C++ `type_info` from the SEH EXCEPTION_RECORD. Technically you did not hit a first chance exception, you are in a break point in RaiseException instead (ie. the exception was *not* yet raised).

Comment: Wow! Thanks for these awesome references. Maybe you should add them directly to your post. I'll have a closer look at your links tomorrow.

Comment: @RalphTandetzky Make sure the first chance exception you're investigating will actually lead to a 2nd chance exception because there could be thousands of first chance exceptions before a 2nd chance occurs.